# Alarm is not triggering at time - perl

Tags: perl

I have used an Alarm function in my script which is not triggering at the time   which it should be :

Here is my code :

```
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub{

         print"*****Test Fail*****";
    };
    eval{
        alarm(10);
        getTheBootTime();
        alarm(0);
    };
    die $@ if $@;
```

getTheBootTime(); is taking **5 mints** to gets execute. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: No, if you dont use `sleep()` inside getTheBootTime. `It is usually a mistake to intermix alarm and sleep calls, because sleep may be internally implemented on your system with alarm.`

Comment: But i am not using any sleep in my code then also i am alarm is not triggering. You want me to copy full function here?

Comment: Just enough to reproduce the problem would be more desirable.

Comment: Shouldn't SIG{ALRM} `die` in this sample instead of just printing? btw, your print statement may get stuck in the buffer until there's a `\n` printed.

Comment: @user1362796, What happens if you replace "print" with "die" in your sample?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that getTheBootTime() is a computation and does NOT tackle with alarm and/or sleep itself, the answer is like follows.

`print "something";` w/o trailing `\n` may not output anything, as printed string gets stuck in the buffer until a newline is printed. This is the default behavior (unless `$|` is set to true or specific file descriptor has autoflush turned on).

Also the specified `$SIG{ALRM}` does NOT interrupt execution (no `die` there) which is what eval/alarm combination expects.

So the following may be in $SIG{ALRM}:

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
     print "alarm, no interruption, newline\n";
};
```

or

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
     die "alarm, interruption";
};
```